# How rotate ModelInstance in translation direction

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm developing simple space game.

I have a class Ship with method move():

```
public void move(Vector3 destination) {
    direction=destination.cpy().sub(position);
    Vector3 movement=direction.cpy().nor().scl(speed);
    position.add(movement);
    instance.transform.setToTranslation(position);
    instance.transform.rotate(face_direction,direction);
}
```

Movement works fine but rotation is incorrect and unpredictable. Please help me orientate ship in moving direction.

Comment: what's transform.rotate()? Maybe you're adding rotation every frame instead of setting the rotation.